# php multiple row data enter in database while clicking on add button

Tags: php

I m create a add button which create a row  contain item name, description,unitcost,quantity,price but how can in save this row in my database only first row data is saved in database but when i click on add row and a new row created but this row data is not insert in my database[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0lHa.png)

Comment: Share some code to show how you are working. Also please edit your question and make clear its not fetching or not inserting

Comment: Didi you check you html through html inspector. i guess your appended row overwrite the old rows.

Comment: Talha malik or tony stark pls sir give me ur mail id or response at my mail  id (nneerajdj@gmail.com) i will show you my code and discuss about my problem

Answer (score 0):

On button click you are creating a new row which have a form you need to initialize your fields (name, description,unitcost,quantity,price) in form of array ... and then when you submit it will post all the values in form of array... like:

```
    <form method="post" action="hello.php">
    <input type="text" name="price[]" />
    </form>
```

On hello.php

```
    $data = $_POST[];
    print_r($data);
```

Which will result all names in your repeated html by clicking button which is enclosed in a single formm....

Or you can share your code u using , so ppl can help better

Comment: please give me your mail id or response at my mail id (nneerajdj@gmail.com)